# Pandas deletes Header of Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, tweets

I am working with a csv that has the sentiment value of a tweet and in the next colum it has the tweet.

```
data = pd.read_csv("Tweets.csv",encoding="utf-8-sig")

print(data)

print(data.dtypes)
```

this puts it out like this:

```
  sentiment,                      tweets
0     neutral                       What @dhepburn said.
```

I used this code to convert everything to lowercase:

```
lower = data['tweets'].str.lower()
```

If I print this, it shows up like this though:

```
0                             what @dhepburn said.
```

The headers are gone and I can't work with this. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to assign back the result:

```
data['tweets'] = data['tweets'].str.lower()
```

**Because:**

- `data['tweets'].str.lower()` : returns a series

Comment: Or you can just wrap the whole expression around a `pd.DataFrame(...)` (just as an additional solution)